# Повторение рисунка в Image

Tags: delphi, изображения

Как можно в компоненте Image с рисунком [image]  сделать повтор с небольшим отступом (желательно прозрачным) [image]

Comment: Элементы с текстурами проще делать через компонент `TPaintBox` с кастомной отрисовкой текстуры через обработчик `OnPaint` на канве компонента.

Answer (score 2):

Cоздайте **`Tbitmap`**, скопируйте туда рисунок, сделайте отступ , и еще раз скопируйте.

А потом сам **`BitMap`** перенесите в **`Image`**

Comment: И как это сделать? Я с графикой в Дельфи не работал.

Comment: читай хелп по **CopyRect**